# How to Enforce Password Complexity Policy settings Windows in local system

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, passwords, group-policy

Is there any way we can enforce the password policy changes with the immediate effect i.e enforce the user to change the password while logon if it is not met newly added policy settings.

I heard that something we can do with Powershell WMI Bridge Scripting. I am very much new to it any help on this topic please.

But as per Miscrosoft

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/hh994562(v=ws.10)

new password policy will come to effect when user changes password manually or age of the policy is over. not immediate.

is there any way we can enforce password change by config change or using powershell script.?

Comment: You can do pretty much anything you want with a PowerShell script, including set the password where it must be changed, and log out the user.

Comment: In my understanding we can do the password complexity change and enforce with AD. is there any way to do with system group policy.  please help me with any resources.

Comment: What have you tried?  The process to enforce this using a local group policy at the machine level should not be any different than enforcing it at the AD domain group policy level.  The only issue you might run into is, if the users are Administrators, they can simply change the policy and flag their account's password as never expiring.

Comment: @Ramhound  In terms of WMI I am not tried anything...as I am not aware that how this one will work.  if you have any sample code for wmi GPO password policy settings?

Comment: @Ramhound in AD this is the setting i observed                                               
 Set-ADUser -Filter * -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$true    is there any such kind of settings in GPO